# Abp Lepton theme: left side menu broken: features[featureKey].toLowerCase() undefined

Tags: angular, abp

**Update**: if you have any problems with Lepton theme, the issue thread on Github is very informative:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/75209544/655605

**Disclaimer:** My question is regarding Abp framework. Volo, the creators, encourage the developers to submit their issues to Stackoverflow.

ABP Framework version: **6.0.1 - Commercial Suite**
Lepton version: **6.0.1**

The project was created using Abp Suite and ran, and this happened:

`ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toLowerCase')`
**in file**: `volo-abp.ng.theme.lepton.mjs:1266:42`

Going to that line in the file this is what I found:

```js
const LEPTON_THEME_FEATURES = new InjectionToken('LEPTON_THEME_FEATURES', {
    providedIn: 'root',
    factory: () => {
        const configState = inject(ConfigStateService);
        const featureKey = 'LeptonManagement.Enable';
        const mapFn = features => ({
            
        // The prolem is here: Uncaught ReferenceError: features is not defined
            enable: features[featureKey].toLowerCase() !== 'false',
        });
        return featuresFactory(configState, [featureKey], mapFn);
    },
});
```

**Note:** ABP Suite is a framework and that code is in their package, I would prefer not to make patches to packages.

**Kindly how do I solve this problem?**

[image]

Comment: 1) It's not my downvote. [Don't assume you know who voted on your posts](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/388686/11107541) 2) People can vote however they want as long as it's not fraudulent voting. Voting is [vital to the health of the system](/help/why-vote). 3) Please always [edit] clarifications into your question post instead of hiding them in the comments! Comments are for _soliciting_ clarifications- not for providing them.

Comment: Thank you for the input. I will add clarification to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have sent the answer on   https://github.com/abpframework/abp/issues/15407
I think some backend configuration of Theme Lepton is missing. Please use updated version of ABP.

Answer (score 0):

I could see only place it broken in your code is this `features[featureKey].toLowerCase()`

Try add safe check.

```
const mapFn = features => {
    let enable = false;
    if (features[featureKey]) {
        enable = features[featureKey].toLowerCase() !== 'false',
    }
   return {
    enable
   }
};
```

Comment: Thank you, Naren. ABP Suite is a framework and that code is in their package, I would prefer not to make patches to packages.

Comment: If you can't patch the code, you have to make sure the `LEPTON_THEME_FEATURES` exists in the configuration accessed by the `ConfigStateService`.

Comment: Also in many csproj files and appsettings.json as well.
@Mahmut Gundogdu's answer on Github was very revealing.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/75209544/655605